# Nuxt/vue scroll always start from top: 0

Tags: vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js

When clicking links within the same page, I wan't a smooth scroll effect.
I get this to partially work when navigating to an element below the viewport.
But when navigating upward, the "scrolling" always start from the top (y: 0 / top: 0) without any scrolling effect. The browser just makes a quick jump to the element.

In other words, it scrolls smoothly downward, but not up.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
router: { 
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) { 
    if (to.hash) { 
      return { behavior: 'smooth'}; 
    } 
    return {x: 0, y: 0} // only for route changes
  }
}
```

Other than that there is no code that controls scrolling in any way.
I do not want to use the css: scroll-behavior: 'smooth', since it messes with some other stuff.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: I've answered some of those questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+scroll

Comment: None of them have the same issue though

Comment: Not sure how this could be an issue here.